# Can't connect to Core data with locked Device

Tags: ios, core-data

My app works with `UILocalnotification` actions. And these actions changes information in Core Data (using normal methods of saving data). the problem is when the device is locked with Passcode and app is closed, i get this error:

```
[Warning] sqlite3 error in _Bool CSDBRecordStoreSaveWithPreAndPostCallbacksAndTransactionType(CSDBRecordStoreRef, CSDBRecordStoreSaveCallback, CSDBRecordStoreSaveCallback, CSDBRecordConflictPolicy, CSDBSqliteTransactionType, CFErrorRef *): disk I/O error

Error saving record store: CSDBRecordSQLite/10
```

I've reading about file protection, but is all disabled in app. This happens only with few devices (in this case, iPod touch 5g)